# Problemas de conexão do PHP com MySQL.(Access denied for user)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

sou iniciante na área que se refere à programação e computadores. Estou com um problema que não consigo a solução em lugar algum.

Tenho uma máquina virtual Linux com um servidor MySQL para suprir a ferramenta de monitoramento Zabbix Server (que já está instalada na máquina virtual). A partir da minha máquina física (Windows) criei um túnel SSH através do Putty, dessa forma consigo conectar o PHP (que instalei via Xampp) ao MySQL da máquina virtual:

```
<?php
   $link = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1:3310','root','senha');
?>
```

A conexão é feita, porém o MySQL me retorna que a senha ou usuário está errado:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'srv-gui'
>   (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\zabbix\index.php on line 2

O usuário e senha estão corretos, isto é fato, já que consigo acessar o console do MySQL com os mesmos.

Agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Já tentou substituir `'127.0.0.1:3310'`por `localhost` ?

Comment: Verificou se o usuário esta habilitado para acessar de qualquer maquina? por padrão se não me engano vem apenas para a maquina que esta instalado acessar usando esse usuário

Comment: Jeferson de que maneira posso habilitar? Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Já tentei Guilherme! Porém não obtive sucesso. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tenta dar acesso para o usuário acessar remotamente

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' 
    IDENTIFIED BY 'YOUR_PASS' 
    WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```